# How to request multiple file in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a functionality where I need the user to upload multiple files/images. The length of the requested files can be dynamic.

```
def add_images(image1: UploadFile = File(...),image2: UploadFile = File(...),image3: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"msg": "success"}
```

As of now, This is the body that I was requesting but I know this is not the ideal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload multiple images by requesting the images as a List of UploadFile.

```
from typing import List

def add_images(images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    // Your image upload code here
    return {"msg": "success"}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dharmik, this solution worked for me.